# Remove HTML tags from Strings on laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to remove HTML tags (all) from a string on laravel blade ...

code

```
{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($subject->body, 5,'...')  !!}
```

output (example)

```
<p>hassen zouari</p>
```

I want it be like this

```
hassen zouari
```

Comment: you can use strip_tags($string) to strip the html tags.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try to use `strip_tags()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

**Update:**
Try to do something like this in a controller:

```
$taglessBody = strip_tags($subject->body);
```

Then pass this variable into a blade template and use it instead of `$subject->body`.

Comment: thanks :) but when i add 
{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($subject->body, 5,'...')  !!} as the string that i want ahnge to this function it shows an error ..

Answer (score 32):

You can use strip_tags($yourString); to strip the html tags. In blade you could achieve this by

```
{{ strip_tags($yourString) }} 
//if your string is <h1> my string </h1>
//output will be my string.
```

hope that is helpful :)

Comment: thanks :) but when i add 
{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($subject->body, 5,'...')  !!} as the string that i want ahnge to this function it shows an error ..

Answer (score 12):

As for me, I use this construction:

```
{!! str_limit(strip_tags($post->text), $limit = 50, $end = '...') !!}
```

I hope, my code was helpful for somebody)

Comment: str_limit doesn't exist now, you can use facade to achieve this functionality.                               {!! Str::limit(strip_tags($post->description), $limit = 50, $end = '...') !!}

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
{{ strip_tags( $value->description ) }}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the below code into your helpers

```
  if (! function_exists('words')) {
        /**
         * Limit the number of words in a string.
         *
         * @param  string  $value
         * @param  int     $words
         * @param  string  $end
         * @return string
         */
        function words($value, $words = 100, $end = '...')
        {
            return \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($value, $words, $end);
        }
    }
```

& use this in your blade

```
{{ words($sentence, $limit = 20, $end = ' ..... more') }}
```

Answer (score 4):

you must know about the diffrence between `{{ }}`  and `{!! !!}`

1.1) laravel have predefined you can load variable exact value  by using `{{$a }}`

or

1.2)laravel loading with strip remove `{!! $a  !!}`

please take it seriously this qustion answer its protect your website from cross site scripting excecution.for example if user save his name but he puted script 
alert.then if you using core php and not handling the strip tags then this script excution when page laod

so i give you some more harmful example
1)like i puted my name as script or in a about section and in script i write some code who get the browser cookies of open website and curl request for saving on my server.

so you understand this whats happen if i got the each user cookies by curl and i just puted a cross script in about filed and its saved in database.

Answer (score 3):

This will solve your issue

```
{!! strip_tags( \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($subject->body, 5,'...')) !!}" }}
```

Comment: this worked for me on laravel 8

Answer (score 1):

just by doing this `{!! $value !!}` will solve your problem

Comment: but you can not apply limit after using this tag.

Comment: Did you mean limiting the characters?

Comment: It will not remove the tags but will apply the HTML on the text. strip_tags will actually remove HTML without applying it.

Answer (score 1):

when we used strip_tags, it will not convert the whitespace into space, it will display as HTML like &nbsp!; this.
How to remove this and the tags too?

```
{!! Str::limit(strip_tags($subject->body), $limit = 50, $end = '...') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in your code

$allcms = json_decode(strip_tags(Cms::where('status','active')->get()),true);

```
  return response()->json(['status' => 'success','message' =>'All CMS','data' => $allcms]);
```

Answer (score 0):

****PHP 8.1 and from Laravel 9, we can do this:****

```
$taglessBody = strip_tags((string) $subject->body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep htmlentities, line break, ...

Long code, but that satisfies me in all situations

```
@php
$txt = nl2br(Str::words(strip_tags($var->txt), 30, '...'));
$txt = preg_replace('/(<br\s*\/?>\s*){2,}/', '<br />', $txt);
@endphp
{!! $txt !!}
```

Explications

1. Remove HTML tags
2. Reduice string to 30 words
3. Replace new lines with BR tags
4. Remove contiguous BR tags