# Removing html tags in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have an issue with deleting HTML tags. Well I get string from database

```
$desc = "<p>Test 1</p>";
```

And when I filter variable with htmlspecialchars and other, I have < and something else. Is there any function which can just remove tags and set variable to

```
$desc = "Test 1";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove HTML tags from Strings on laravel blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247382/remove-html-tags-from-strings-on-laravel-blade)

Comment: @L.Guthardt, I wouldn't say this problem is a duplicate if you read the comments below within the answers.

Comment: {!! $desc !!} Add this one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use `{!! $variable !!}` to remove the tags from being visible on the output.

**Updated after further clarification from the op**

because of the output you will need to use: `strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($desc))`

Comment: I have try that, but don' work :( http://prntscr.com/ihrikt http://prntscr.com/ihrisb

Comment: Are you using `$desc = "<p>Test 1</p>";` within the view?

Comment: What type on the DB side is `description` being saved as, varchar or text?

Comment: I get $random ($random from repository, which is sent with comapct from controller and goes in blade foreach, and echo)

Comment: Yes but I assume your description is stored on a database no?

Comment: $table->text('description'); (from migrations)

Comment: Sorry but i don't know what you mean :/

Comment: description -> text :)

Comment: Within your database you can view the content of each input. Do these store the tags such as `<p>`?

Comment: Ok so your tags aren't inputting correctly. If you dd($random->description) what does this give?

Comment: Updated the answer for you.

Comment: No problem at all glad i could help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($desc))
```

If you want to print the string with these tags used as tags:

```
{!! $desc !!}
```

Comment: I have try that, but don' work :( prntscr.com/ihrikt prntscr.com/ihrisb

Comment: I'm pretty sure `strip_tags` will work. Please show how exactly are you trying to use it.

Comment: @Sava if `dd($random->description)` gives you this string `"<p>Test 1</p>"`, then the code will work.

Comment: they store like "&lt;p&gt;Test!&lt;/p&gt;"

Answer (score 1):

`{!!$description!!}`

This is the code to remove html code however in some situation it may not work so you can also use this

```
{!! nl2br(@$description) !!}
```

However you can also use

```
strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($description))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) {

    preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags);
    $tags = array_unique($tags[1]);

    if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) {
        if($invert == FALSE) {
            return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
        }
        else {
            return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
        }
    }
    elseif($invert == FALSE) {
        return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}

public function isolate($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = $this->strip_tags_content($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $data);
    $data = strtolower($data);
    return $data;
}
```