# Laravel 9 How to remove html tag in sending email?

Tags: laravel, html-email, laravel-9

guys I was facing problems when sending an email. As you can see the <p tag is exist in the content. How should I solve this problem? Hereby, I provide my source code.
[image]

**emailController.blade.php**

```
$AlertData = [
            'subject'=>$title,
            'Name'=>'Hello, '.$name,
            'body' => $content,
            'AlertText'=>'Alert',
            'url'=>url('/'),
            'thankyou'=>'Thank you.',
            'regards'=>'Regards,'.$landlord_name
        ];
        $user ->notify(new Email($AlertData));
```

**view.blade.php**

```
 <div class="row mb-3">
                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Description</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea name="description" id="default" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div >
```

Comment: Safer option is to save `$content` in DB without HTML tags. Alternative is to output variable in view file and display unescaped data. Which you should't do if you don't know all consequences. To understand all consequences learn about XSS (cross site scripting).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as i was getting the input from textarea so somehow it will save it with HTML tags. I would try to understand the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find the solution.
It can be doned through **strip_tags()**syntax. So I just need to put $content variable into it.

Resources:
[Remove HTML tags from Strings on laravel blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247382/remove-html-tags-from-strings-on-laravel-blade)

Comment: You can use `new HtmlString("<b>this is a text</b>"))` even